# How to silence statsmodels.fit() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, stdout, statsmodels

When I want to fit some model in python,
I often use `fit()` method in `statsmodels`.
And some cases I write a script for automating fitting:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')  # contains column x and y
fitted = smf.poisson('y ~ x', df).fit()
```

My question is how to silence the `fit()` method.
In my environment it outputs some information about fitting to standard output like:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 2.397867
         Iterations 11
```

but I don't need it.
I couldn't find the argument which controls standard output printing.
How can I silence `fit()` method?

Python 3.3.4, IPython 2.0.0, pandas 0.13.1, statsmodels 0.5.0.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the disp argument to fit. It controls the verbosity of the optimizers in scipy.

```
mod.fit(disp=0)
```

See the documentation for fit.

Comment: `disp` is exactly what I needed. Of course I saw the documentation for `fit` but I missed it. Please excuse my stupidity.